# C# code for sms and email notification service

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, email, alert, reminders

I'm working on ASP.Net MVC 3.0 SQL Server Entity frame work
I need to create a Daily Reminder system, in which a user would enter the email address and the reminder timings like 1st Reminder(9 AM), 2nd reminder(12PM) and 3rd reminder(6PM), and the system should send out emails at those timings.

What's the best way to send out emails, when the time criteria is met.
Please suggest different ways to accomplish this task.

Comment: Sounds suspiciously like homework? What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

Basically you want to send email as schedule job and for that we all quickly think as Windows Service sitting in background and doing the scheduled job

But if you want achieve similar via ASP.NET please read more on this class [CacheItemRemovedCallback](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.caching.cacheitemremovedcallback.aspx)

Their is a very nice blog written and shown with agood example at https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/07/easy-background-tasks-in-aspnet/

Comment: looks interesting. will try background task in ASP.Net and update you how it will go- thanks